# How to restore Git submodule after deleting it?

Tags: git, github

I accidentally deleted a submodule directory/repository. After doing `git submodule init` i tried running `git submodule update` which gives me the following error:

> fatal: Not a git repository: ../../.git/modules/externals/foo
>
> Unable to find current revision in submodule path 'externals/foo'

Can somebody please tell me what i am doing wrong?

EDIT: I deleted the submodule directory, I can clone the submodule repository for which the link is in .gitmodules, but I read somewhere that i can completely delete submodules by deleting the .git/modules/externals folder which i deleted (I dont know if this was right thing to do) anyway i downloaded the repository and pasted on the location where the submodule is supposed to exist but that is now the correct way.
`git submodule` gives the following output:

> +244d6addc83d1cc801ff1880f71574d3fcc6b77e externals/foo (heads/master)

Comment: The question is unclear. Which one did you delete? The submodule directory is in the working area. You get it back by git update. The error message looks like more than a deleted submodule directory. The submodule repo (the object store) is located under .git/modules/... of the top level repo. If you delete it you need to have another repo where git submodule update can clone from again, otherwise it is lost. You need to give more details before the question can be answered. In the main repo: what does the file .gitmodules contain? What does git submodule say? What does git diff say?

Comment: So you deleted first the submodule directory and later even the submodule repo (object store). Downloading and pasting data should never be necessary, probably something went wrong there. What about 1.) submodule deinit 2.) delete all pasted data 3.) git submodule init 4.) git submodule update

Comment: i get: `error: pathspec 'deinit' did not match any file(s) known to git` when i ran: `git submodule deinit foo` ..

Comment: I also get `Did you forget to 'git add'?` ..

Comment: I tested deleting both the submodule directory and the submodule repo (object store under .git/modules of the main repo). Still git submodule update is enough the recover both (assuming that the submoule can still be cloned from the original location). The deinit suggestion was just because you seem to have a more inconsistent state. The deinit command works for me, you need to give the full local path of the submodule (incorrect path will result in the message you quoted). From the error message in the original question that path would be externals/foo.

Comment: `git submodule update externals/foo` seems to work now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

I recovered my working copy using comment made by @UweGeuder:

```
git submodule deinit -f .
git submodule update --init
```